# Raspberry Pi 4 B - Multi-Port Charger Recommendations? (Or is 2.4A fine?)

Tags: pi-4

Thing needs 5V/3A, but **every** charger on Amazon with > 1 port seems to offer a max of 2.4A per port. I can live with using (2) chargers w/ 3 ports each (6 total, for 6 raspberry pis), but its a challenge to even find that.

Is there a place to buy such a thing or is 2.4A fine?

Comment: The official advice is to use an OFFICIAL Pi SUPPLY. Chargers are designed to CHARGE BATTERIES

Comment: Most of the time, the ports are placed in parallel and it's just the port that's rated at 2.4A. You could connect the 2 port together to get more amps.

Answer (score 2):

You should never run a Pi from a charger.  It is feasible for the charger to drop the voltage to below the working limits of the Pi as the current requirement increases.  They also suffer from small voltage drops randomly unless they are of good quality.

You would do much better to get a decent 5v power supply or use the 5v output from a PC power supply and test the load capabilities with a good load tester and meter.

For any number of Pis over two, I would look at how they are mounted and fed:

- DIN Rail mounts are available from some suppliers
- Rack mount kits are available from some suppliers
- Blade mount kits for large numbers of Pi boards

Each of these have power options that are designed for stability and long running - often using the J8 connector rather than the USB port.  I find the [BitScope](https://www.bitscope.com/product/blade/?p=about) boards give lots of flexibility over the DIN Rail or traditional rack mount style BUT I get into trouble over loose cables!

Comment: Oops, I'm running my Pi's on my 2.4A chargers. Never had problems

Comment: Took me weeks to sort WiFi issues with Pi running off a 3A charger - soon as I swapped they all went.  I only use decent supplies now not chargers for anything over a zero.

Comment: RPi4 or earlier versions? RPi4 is notorious for it's WiFi problems coupled with the HDMI.

Comment: 3 or 3+ - it was when I first started with the bigger boards - I did not have any issues with the Zero and Zero W boards (even had them plugged into the back of my home router once) and never gave it any thought (blush).